# How to increment value when the button click laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

im using laravel 5.3 and the project is shooping cart 
When I click the items the quantity is not increment

the Product Controll

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
{
  $product  =Product::find($id);
  $oldcart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
  $cart = new Cart($oldcart);
  $cart->add($product , $product->id);

  $request->session()->put('cart',$cart);
// TO show it  dd($request->Session()->get('cart'));
  return redirect()->route('product.index');
}
```

and the model Cart :

```
 class Cart
 {
 public $items = null;
public $totalQty = 0;
public $totalPrice = 0;

public function __consruct($oldCart){
  if($oldCart){
    $this->$items = $oldCart->items;
    $this->$totalQty  = $oldCart->totalQty;
    $this ->$totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
  }

}
   public function add($item,$id){
    $storedItem = ['qty' => 0,'price' => $item->price,'item' => $item];
    if ($this->items)
    {
      if(arrary_Key_exists($id,$this->items))
      {
        $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
      }
    }
      $storedItem['qty']++;
      $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
      $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
      $this->totalQty++;
      $this->totalPrice += $item->price;

  }

  }
```

And this is a Product page:

```
  <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shopping Cart
        <span class="badge">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '' }}</span>
      </a>
```

it should add the item and increment but it's just show the id of item with out increment it .

Answer (score 0):

Session is saved as a flash data. So, you need to save the session whenever you push the data. Since you are not doing it in your code always gets a fresh new cart with 1st item being added to it and i think you are confusing that number with the ID since totalQty will always be 1.

So please do the following after putting the cart object in session.

```
$request->session()->save();
```

Comment: Okay lets do two things. First Get this  ternary operators value in getAddToCart and remove it from the blade. In the past for me sometime ternary operators mess up in blade templates. Secondly can you please share the result when you dumo entire session using dd($request->session()->all()); OR print_r(session()->all()) ;

Answer (score 0):

you mean this

```
    array:4 [▼
 "_token" => "NaciZTnMzNzqB02Nvr7RtXJj7c5NtsUF339522l2"
 "_previous" => array:1 [▼
   "url" => "http://localhost:8000"
    ]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▼
"old" => []
"new" => []
]  

Cart {#163 ▼
+items: array:1 [▼
1 => array:3 [▼
  "qty" => 1
  "price" => 20
  "item" => Product {#172 ▼
    #fillable: array:4 [▼
      0 => "imgaePath"
      1 => "title"
      2 => "description"
      3 => "price"
    ]
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:7 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "imagePath" => "http://www.abebooks.com/images/books/harry-potter/deathly-hallows.jpg"
      "title" => "hurry potter"
      "description" => "the best book ever"
      "price" => 20
    ]
    #original: array:7 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "imagePath" => "http://www.abebooks.com/images/books/harry-potter/deathly-hallows.jpg"
      "title" => "hurry potter"
      "description" => "the best book ever"
      "price" => 20
    ]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▼
      0 => "*"
    ]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
   }
]
]
+totalQty: 1
+totalPrice: 20
 }
```

Comment: Can you do the following : $cart->save() before saving it in session. Also we can use $request->session()->push($cart.items,'cart_items') to store cart items in the session and retrieve them as array and from count() of that array we can always get the total count of items.

Comment: it's give me an erorr  Call to undefined method App\Cart::save()   or        Use of undefined constant items - assumed 'items'

Comment: did you import Cart model file in your controller where you are using it.

Comment: yeh  import it in model  use App\Cart;

Comment: Okay and in your model Cart i see extend Eloquent is mssing. Please add that and check.

Comment: it's show Trying to get property of non-object    view

Comment: Bro that clearly means the way you are handling oldCart object is not legit. I advise you to push cart items in an array to session and get the count of these back in your blade template to find the total number of items.

Comment: i watch this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_5BZKe0Ab4&list=PL55RiY5tL51qUXDyBqx0mKVOhLNFwwxvH&index=10) it's work for him

Comment: Awesome. Sorry couldn't help you bro 